# My Python Rest API hangs on CURL

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I created a simple REST API in Python using Flask.  The code for that service is:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Ping(Resource):
    def get(self):
        resp = jsonify({"response": 'Pong!'})
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp

api.add_resource(Ping, '/ping')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I start the service with: `$python minimal-rest.py`

I curl the ping endpoint with: `$ curl -i  http://127.0.0.1:5000/ping` and the results are exactly what I expect.

I then hit the same endpoint from a browser, and again the results are as expected.

If I issue another curl command, the console just hangs.  However, if I then go refresh my browser, it responds, as well as the console that was running the hung curl.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are already retrieving the header. It Keep Alive set?

Comment: The sum of my knowledge regarding keep alive could fit in a thimble with room to spare. :)  Everything that I am doing is contained in the original question. Is there is more that I need?

Comment: Let me ask it in an other way: What is the full result of your `curl` call?

Comment: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26
Server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/2.7.13
Date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 18:07:11 GMT

{
  "response": "Pong!"
}

Comment: It does not seem to be related to keep alive.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Ping` class:

```
class Ping(Resource):
    def get(self):
        resp = {"response": 'Pong!'}
        return resp, 200
```